# Como deixar minha GridView no meio da tela?

Tags: c#

Como deixar minha GridView c# no meio da tela ?

ja tentei coloca-la em uma div e atribur aling = center
mas não deu certo.

Alguem tem uma sugestão ?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4"
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign = "Center">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Poste seu código, por favor

Comment: Dê uma medida a GridView e  tipo style="width:500px;margin:0 auto 0 auto;" talvez ajude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tudo bem?

Quando você está criando um GridView em uma página ASP.Net, uma das coisas que você pode tentar é colocar uma `<div></div>` em torno dele, a fim de centralizar o GridView na página, através da atribuição de `text-align: center` para o seu div , mas isso não vai funcionar. Pois os mais recentes CSS não funcionam desta forma =(.

A fim de fazer isso, supondo que você tenha uma classe CSS que você está usando com o GridView, basta adicionar o seguinte CSS para sua classe:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O `margin: 0 auto;` simplifica isso @Danilo. Porém é a mesma coisa. :)